# Terraform Override Provider for use with Localstack

Tags: terraform, localstack

I have a Git Repository with Terraform code that is being deployed into AWS. I am adding Localstack to this repository so that I can do higher-level validation testing before a plan and apply into my real AWS account. In order to use Localstack I have to create a new provider with the custom endpoint:

```
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "real"
  region = "${local.aws_region}"
}

provider "aws" {
  alias                       = "fake"
  region                      = "${local.aws_region}"
  access_key                  = "fake"
  secret_key                  = "fake"
  skip_credentials_validation = true
  skip_metadata_api_check     = true
  skip_requesting_account_id  = true

  endpoints {
    dynamodb = "http://localhost:4566"
    lambda   = "http://localhost:4566"
    kinesis  = "http://localhost:4566"
  }
}
```

How can I use one provider for Localstack and one provider with AWS without duplicating my code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately because the configuration structure is quite significantly different between these two cases it's not really possible to make this dynamically switchable without the resulting configuration looking quite complicated, but it *is* possible to use Terraform language expression operators and `dynamic` blocks to set all of the provider arguments conditionally, and thus have a single provider configuration with dynamic settings rather than two separate provider configurations.

The first thing to decide would be how you'll decide between the two possibilities. Since your localstack pseudo-infrastructure will unavoidably be distinct from the "real" infrastructure I expect you'll want to use a separate state for it, and so this could be a reasonable situation to use a separate [workspace](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/state/workspaces.html) for development/testing, and I'll write this example assuming that the localstack configuration should be active whenever the workspace `dev` is selected. If that isn't what you want then hopefully this should still be enough to adapt to match your needs.

```
locals {
  use_localstack = (terraform.workspace == "dev")

  aws_settings = (
    local.use_localstack ?
    {
      region     = local.aws_region
      access_key = "fake"
      secret_key = "fake"

      skip_credentials_validation = true
      skip_metadata_api_check     = true
      skip_requesting_account_id  = true

      override_endpoint = "http://localhost:4566"
    } :
    {
      region     = local.aws_region
      access_key = null
      secret_key = null
      
      skip_credentials_validation = null
      skip_metadata_api_check     = null
      skip_requesting_account_id  = null

      override_endpoint = null
    }
  )
}

provider "aws" {
  region     = local.aws_settings.region
  access_key = local.aws_settings.access_key
  secret_key = local.aws_settings.secret_key

  skip_credentials_validation = local.aws_settings.skip_credentials_validation
  skip_metadata_api_check     = local.aws_settings.skip_metadata_api_check
  skip_requesting_account_id  = local.aws_settings.skip_requesting_account_id

  dynamic "endpoints" {
    for_each = local.aws_settings.override_endpoint[*]
    content {
      dynamodb = endpoints.value
      lambda   = endpoints.value
      kinesis  = endpoints.value
    }
  }
}
```

The above is relying on two particular behaviors of the Terraform language:

- When setting arguments that will be passed to a provider, setting `null` is always the same as omitting that argument, because Terraform internally handles unset arguments by implicitly setting them to `null` anyway.
- Using [`[*]`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/splat.html) with a non-list value automatically converts it into a zero-element list or a one-element list, depending on whether the value is `null`. That allows us to [dynamically declare the `endpoints` block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html) only if the `override_endpoint` attribute is non-null, and then write its value into all three of the overridden endpoint arguments.

Comment: Thanks Martin! This is a great solution that works and keeps my code dry.

Comment: The only thing this doesn't address is the matter of the backend. When I'm running in the real world I use a state bucket. If I leave the backend in the code it assumes a  real provider and I get `No valid credential sources found for AWS Provider`. Without the backend I'm fine. Is there any way to conditionally use s3 vs local backend?

Comment: In Terraform the backend is fixed for each configuration, and so if you need two different backends then I'd typically recommend writing two configurations that both call the same shared module but have different backend configurations, though that's quite a different design than what I suggested here were I assumed it was only provider configurations you needed to deal with.

Comment: However, since in this case you'd presumably be using `backend "s3"` in both cases and only the arguments would differ, you could look into running `terraform init` with the `-backend-config=FILENAME` option to specify a set of overridden settings. Beware that by default Terraform will think you're trying to _migrate_ your configuration's backend to a new location and so will prompt you about that. You can use the `-reconfigure` option to tell Terraform to ignore any existing backend configuration, but you'll need to remember to initialize back to normal before working with real infrastructure

Comment: A separate configuration for each context and a shared module for the common parts is the more "foolproof" solution, since that totally segregates the two situations and makes it much harder to accidentally make messes like e.g. using the dev provider configuration against the non-dev backend or vice-versa.

Comment: I guess one final idea is to just let your `dev` workspace exist in your remote S3 backend, even though its state won't really make much sense outside of your dev environment, and then you can avoid the need to reinit with different settings but still get broadly the same effect otherwise.

Comment: This is a great answer that was useful to me. I wrote a blog post explaining how to use localstack to test your terraform thanks to it https://www.willmunn.xyz/terraform/aws/devops/lambda/ioc/localstack/2023/04/29/using-localstack-to-test-terraform.html